# Android Download Manager with get request

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have implemented Download Manager  code for download excel file from server, but not able to download.

Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://myip/getfile?param1=value1&param2=value2")

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
request.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
request.setDescription(getString(R.string.msg_wait_for_download));
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
    getString(R.string.app_name)+File.separator+"statement_xyz.xls");

long refid = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: can you put a sample link here, seems like the issue is with your url. It may not be directly downloadable

Comment: When I run same url in chrome file is downloading